# Request.Form removing + sign from the value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ashx handler in asp.net webform (.net 3.5) application in which i have to initialize some object with form field data.
One of a field is  "To" is a telephone field having data like To=+1852931591
Problem is that when I am filling it into object by simply context.Request.Form["To"] it is removing + sign.
I have even tried htmlencode/decode but nothing work.

My code is like

```
var listValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (string key in context.Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(k)))
                {
                    listValues.Add(key, context.Request.Form[key]);
                }
```

Comment: is this a POST or a GET request?

Comment: Try a Server.HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode or Server.UrlEncode/Decode, or Replace " " with "+" (this last one feels sloppy, but sometimes you just need to get it to work)

Comment: Have tried htmlencode/decode but no use. replacing " " to + not seems to be good idea to me

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a way of indicating spaces in URLs. That value will be interpreted as `[space]1852931591`.

If you want to have a plus sign in a query value, you'll need to encode it as `%2B` or preferably encode all of your query values with something like `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: This request is coming from some external source .I have to simply catch the callback and on that bases do some stuff